# Enumerating remote services

Tags: .net

`ServiceController.GetServices()` from the `System.ServiceProcess` namespace can be used to enumerate servers on the local machine, or a remote machine by passing its netbios name as a parameter.

Under the covers this is done via Windows NT RPC - which of course means it is authenticated using users credentials.

In an Active Directory (previously Windows NT Domain) environment this means that the AD user's permissions are checked on the target PC to see if he has been assigned the privileges necessary to access the list of Services - and, for example - Domain Admins usually would.

In an environment where the software is not being run under an AD Domain Admin account, or simply in an environment where AD accounts are not being used to control access, but some non AD account has been setup remotely, we need to ensure the correct remote account is being used.

In the native world, we would call `LogonUser` passing a flag that clones the current access token - ensuring all local access remains unchanged, but alters the remote credentials to those provided (without doing any checks), then call `'ImpersonateUser` to make that new token current, and then perform the operation than invokes the RPC.

.Net provides for this via WindowsIdentity.Impersonate() from the System.Security.Principal namespace. All we need is a WindowsIdentity that represents the current user but with altered/provided remote credentials...

Here the trail runs cold. WindowsIdentity objects always seem to be provided by some framework, and/or the static variant of the `Impersonate` method takes an IntPtr parameter that is the native handle returned from `LogonUser`, but we've come this far without resorting to a PInvoke, surely we can close the loop without leaving managed code?

No. There seems to be a strange gap in the .net functionality coverage: A bunch of seemingly well supported and documented objects that simply cannot be used without a PInvoke (or the use of a 3rd party library to hide the PInvoke).

I see even the MSDN articles on these functions all just brazenly include calls to the advapi:LogonUser native API but my mind rebels. Surely, surely, there is some way to construct a WindowsIdentity with remote credentials without leaving managed code?

Comment: "construct a WindowsIdentity with remote credentials without leaving managed code"   you'll likely have to build one yourself. Beware of scepticism, asking 'id like to fake the security system' wont always bring good suggestions :P

Comment: What? I am not trying to hack anything. I just want a legitimate WindowsIdentity with config provided remote credentials that I can make current (Impersonate()) while performing calls to ServiceController targeting a remote PC.

Comment: Uh huh. Bon chance!

Comment: Is that really a question? Everyone playing .NET should be aware of that fact for long. PInvoke is almost always necessary if you do want to dive deeper into Windows/AD specific.